# ServiceStack can't convert OrmLiteConnectionFactory to IDbConnectionFactory

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

new to ServiceStack and need some instructions.

I'm looking to connect my ServiceStack application to SQL Server but got stuck. I read OrmLiteConnectionFactory is inherited from IDbConnectionFactory but the code is underlined with red:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(Properties.Settings.Default.SQLEXPRESSConnectionString,
               SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance));
```

and the error message is:

```
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory' to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbConnectionFactory'
```

This is inside `AppHost.cs's Configure` method.

Any suggestion on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're registering the wrong `IDbConnectionFactory` interface, since you have more than 1 you can use the fully-qualified type name, e.g:

```
container.Register<ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory>(
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString,
    SqlServerDialect.Provider));
```